# Custom node routing

Tags: routes

I have a product content type with alias: /products/headphone. This product page has  two url variations:

- /products/headphone/wire
- /products/headphone/wireless

Both urls should point to the same node, however within preprocess function or twig, I should be able to capture which variation is loaded (wire|wireless)

I figured I should create a custom module and handle custom routing:

my_module.routing.yml:

```
my_module.modality:
  path: '/products/{product_slug}/{variation}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\ProductController::action'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
  options:
    parameters:
      product_slug:
        type: string
      variation:
        type: string
```

The part I'm struggling with is how to point the controller back to preprocess function:

```
function my_module_preprocess_node__product_page(array &$variables){
  // some preprocess stuff
}
```

This is what I currently have in my controller:

\Drupal\my_module\Controller\ProductController:action

```
public function action($program_slug, $variation) 
{
return [
        'template' => 'node--program_page',
        'variation' => $variation
      ];
 }
```

Comment: This is not a good approach. You are trying to re-invent how Drupal is displaying entities. The quickest way is probably to remove the last part of the path in a path processor with a high priority and then let the normal Drupal routing let resolve the product node and render it, which then invokes the preprocess hook automatically.
For the path processor I've described in a different question how to create the code with drush: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/307416/47547